# How to traverse the AST using the language-javascript module?

Tags: haskell

Assuming I have a program like so:

```js
let words = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"]

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  console.log(words[i])
}
```

I want to filter the AST and only keep the literals.
How can I traverse the AST to keep only "foo", "bar", etc?

```hs
literals :: JSAST -> [String]
literals (JSAstProgram statements) = undefined
literals _ = []
```

The undefined line should filter the `[JSStatement]`, and then look for possible expressions.
If an expression is found, check if there's a literal.
Lastly, map the list from a `JSStatement` -> `String`.

Looking for the possible expressions is the problem for me right now. I could pattern match:

```hs
f :: JSStatement -> a
f (JSLet _ expression _) = undefined
f (JSConstant _ expression _) = undefined
f (JsDoWhile _ _ _ _ expression _ _) = undefined
... etc
```

And then same thing for looking for the literal:

```hs
g :: JSExpression -> a
g (JSLiteral _ literal) = undefined
g (JSStringLiteral _ literal) = undefined
g (JSArrayLiteral _ literal _) = undefined
... etc
```

However, this is very verbose and I feel like there's something better out there.
How do I traverse through the AST and filter out only the literals in a clean and concise manner?

Comment: Uniplate would be the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the types in `Language.JavaScript.Parser` are instances of [`Data.Data`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Data.html#t:Data), a class for folding generically over data constructors. You can use [`gmapQ`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Data.html#v:gmapQ), a function from this class, to traverse the structure, and [`cast`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:cast) to determine when you've found a node of interest. Below is an implementation for a simpler example AST type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Data (Data, gmapQ)
import Data.Typeable (cast)

data Lit = S String | I Int deriving Data
data Expr = Sum Expr Expr | LitExpr Lit deriving Data
data Statement = Stmt [Expr] deriving Data
data AST = AST [Statement] deriving Data

strings :: AST -> [String]
strings = concat . gmapQ go
  where go :: Data d => d -> [String]
        go x = case cast x of
          Nothing -> concat $ gmapQ go x
          Just (I _) -> []
          Just (S s) -> [s]

λ> strings (AST [Stmt [], Stmt [LitExpr (S "x"), Sum (LitExpr (I 5)) (LitExpr (S "y")), LitExpr (S "z")]])
["x","y","z"]
```

Note by the way that I needed to give `go` an explicit type signature. I think this is because otherwise GHC was inferring that the recursive call to `go` must use the same `d` constraint as the enclosing call, but of course we need them to differ.

Comment: Do you mind showing a small example of how this works? Doesn't need to be with the AST from language-javascript.
I'm not sure how to use it off of the type-definition itself

Comment: Sure, I've added an example. I'm sure uniplate is lovely, but reading its documentation left me totally baffled about how I would do anything, whereas Data.Data was clear enough to let me write this implementation after never using Data before.

Comment: I added a uniplate solution to the same. It's really much much easier to use compared to use of `Data.Data`.

Comment: It'll take me awhile to break everything down to understand what's going on, but thank you so much for the example! I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

You're right that these sorts of things are usually boilerplate; and Haskell has excellent libraries to let you code such functions easily. One of my favorites is uniplate: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate

Following @amalloy's example, here's how you'd code the same using Uniplate:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Data
import qualified Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data as G

data Lit       = S String | I Int            deriving Data
data Expr      = Sum Expr Expr | LitExpr Lit deriving Data
data Statement = Stmt [Expr]                 deriving Data
data AST       = AST [Statement]             deriving Data

strings :: AST -> [String]
strings a = [s | S s <- G.universeBi a]
```

And then:

```
*Main> strings (AST [Stmt [], Stmt [LitExpr (S "x"), Sum (LitExpr (I 5)) (LitExpr (S "y")), LitExpr (S "z")]])
["x","y","z"]
```

Note that the definition of strings is literally a one-liner. So, all you need is one line of import, and one line for extracting all literals using uniplate's `universeBi` function, which is literally the expression:

```hs
   [s | S s <- G.universeBi ast]
```

which pretty much reads exactly what you intended: Traverse the entire AST, and find me all literal strings appearing anywhere. Doesn't get any more declarative than that!

Comment: Oh wow that's really short compared to the ``Data`` package.
I wish I could select your answer too! Stack overflow doesn't let me upvote it since I'm a new user unfortunately.
Thanks a lot for your example as well, I appreciate it